# Regular expression: count consecutive occurrence xquery

Tags: xml, regex, xquery

I have a sequence of xml elements like this:

```
<addr>via roma</addr>
<addr>via milano</addr>
<addr>via napoli</addr>
...
```

and I want to check if there is a sequence of addresses containing the same consecutive address 3 or more times, like:

```
<addr> via napoli</addr>
<addr>via roma</addr>
<addr>via roma</addr>
<addr>via roma</addr>
<addr>via milano</addr>
....
```

This input sequence of xml elements is the result of xquery. I think I should use the `fn:matches()` function but I can't write the regular expression that matches this sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This query (and Xpath 3.0 expression) produces `true()` exactly when the sequence `$seq` contains $n or more consecutive items having the same string value**:

```
    boolean($seq
              [some $i in 1 to count($seq) -($n -1)
                 satisfies
                    not(distinct-values(subsequence($seq, $i, $n))[2])
              ]
             )
```

**So, in this specific case**:

```
let $n := 3,
    $seq := /*/addr
 return
        boolean($seq
                  [some $i in 1 to count($seq) -($n -1)
                     satisfies
                        not(distinct-values(subsequence($seq, $i, $n))[2])
                  ]
                 )
```

**produces**

```
true
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regular expressions. If `$addrs` is a sequence of `addr` elements, then

```
for $a at $i in $addrs
  let $text := string($a)
  where string($addrs[($i + 1)]) eq $text and string($addrs[($i + 2)]) eq $text
  return ($i, $a)
```

gives you the elements and indices in `$addrs` where a subsequence of three equal consecutive addresses starts, in this case `(2, <addr>via roma</addr>)`.

Note that you will get duplicate addresses when such subsequences of length >4 exist in `$addrs`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
<addr>([^<>]*)<\/addr>\s*<addr>\1<\/addr>\s*<addr>\1<\/addr>
```